# using ajax in zend framework 1.12

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

I'm beginner in zend framework and ajax
I try to do a simple code with ajax and zend , 
it contain a div , text and button when the button is pressed the value of the text is populated into the div 
however when I press the button nothing is happened 
:S
here is my codes please help me

this is the layout

/index/test.phtml

---

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"       type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--for display text and submit fields i use viewHelpers it's very comfortable  and       easy way.-->
<div class="submit_area">
  <?php echo $this->formText('message', 'empty', array('size' => 32, 'id' => 'message')) ?>
  <?php echo $this->formSubmit('submitTo', 'submit', array('id' => 'submitTo')) ?>
  <div class="show-msg"></div>
</div>

<script >
//for send data i'll use jquery library
$(document).ready( function() {
  <?php echo "ready" ?>
  //By clicking on button submit condition makes validate on empty message 
  //unless field message will be not empty  , the programm make send data to
  //controller via ajax
  $("#submitTo").click(function() {
    var message = $('#message').val();
    if (message != '') {
      //run ajax 
      $.post('index/ajax', {'message' : message},
        //callback function
        function (respond) {
          //put respond in class show-msg                          
          $(".show-msg").html(respond);                  
        }
      );
    }                    
  });
});
</script>
```

### --------------------------------------------

### and this is the code in controller

---

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function checkAction()
    {
        // action body  
        $request = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        //referring to the index
        //gets value from ajax request
        $message = $request['message'];

        // makes disable renderer
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

        //makes disable layout
        $this->_helper->getHelper('layout')->disableLayout();

        //return callback message to the function javascript
        echo $message; 
    }

    public function testAction()
    {
        // action body      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting any error?

There are a couple of things I can see in your code that might be wrong.

1. The `click()` event doesn't `return false` so probably your form is submitted before the Ajax call takes place.
2. The Ajax URL points to `/index/ajax` which means the `IndexController` should have an `ajaxAction`. You should point the `post()` request to `/index/check`.

You might also want to have a look at [ContextSwitch and AjaxContext](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch)

Indeed what @Boulevard said is also correct, that `echo` breaks your JS.

Comment: thnks I change the action to check and now I get a post 
but still no value popualted in the div 
I get as shown here
http://www7.0zz0.com/2013/09/29/09/297704652.png

Answer (score 0):

Your code error on javascript syntax.
Try removing this line:

```
  <?php echo "ready" ?>
```

And add javascript close tag:

```
</script>
```

Comment: thnxx I remove it ,, but still no value appears in the div